# Azure AD challenge in Asp.Net Core Web Api + my own JWT bearer

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory

I need to challange Azure AD sign in followed by getting user info from JWT token (mail/ name/ group etc. included in data segment of the token) that I got when I signed-in and validate it in WebApi.

Then check weather the mail is already registered or not:

- if it is not: make new accout using inner api UserManager
- if it is: sign the user in and make him JWT token from INNER WebApi bearer (service)

The point is to get rid of Azure AD JWT token in SPA ReactJS front-end. Once the user clicks the "Sign-in with Azure AD" button backend should take action as I described before. 
After successful sign in frontend should get JWT token generated with my Web Api for authorization inside frontend components.

TO CONCLUDE: all I really wanna ask for is the method to:

1. do this so called "CHALLENGE" (redirect to Azure AD login page)
2. get redirected to frontend after successful sign-in
3. get Azure AD JWT token (as a string or JwtSecurityToken instance) in
   backend to validate once again inside my Api and work on it

I have AD set up and app registered on Azure. In Startup.cs file I "declared" JwtBearer authentication scheme named "Azure" and my own - named "Inner", moreover I made an authorization policy for each one of them.

What I thought of is to make an endpoint destined to provoke the challenge and then make use of fresh JWT token to sign user in with the one I want him to.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer("InnerJwt", options =>
                {
                   <some options>
                })
                .AddJwtBearer("AzureJwt", options =>
                {
                    var authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureAdOptions>();

                    options.Audience = authSettings.ClientId; //Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                    options.Authority = authSettings.Authority; //Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"];
                });

//clientId, tenant and authority are waiting in appsettings.json file already

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("InnerJwt")
                .Build();


                options.AddPolicy("Inner", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("InnerJwt")
                    .Build());

                options.AddPolicy("Azure", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureJwt")
                    .Build());
            });
```

An error I encountered is that Challange()

```cs
public Task<IActionResult> SignIn()
        {
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "<redirect uri>" },
                "AzureJwt");
        }
```

is not recognized method even though I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.{Mvc, Authentication} with newest references to those packages - I don't get it...

**EDIT:**

*Alright I was so stupid that I forgot to inherit that controller from ControllerBase, thus the ControllerBase.Challenge() method was not recoginized.
Now It works but when I manage to go on the right route to "call" this action it returns a 401 NOT AUTHORIZED ERROR in my web browser, instead of leading me to Azure AD sing-in site :/*

Should I do it some other way?

Hopefully this is enough info of what I want to achive if not I'll add it some time later.

Thank you for your time...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?